# ScrollView with multiple Views iOS Autolayout

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout, xcode7

I am a newbie iOS developer currently working for a small company. I started developing iOS only some months ago and i only know how to work with Swift and AutoLayout. I have a little bit of a situation since my boss asked me to do a complicated scrollable view that contains other type of views within it.

I made a sketch using wireframe that is available here: https://wireframe.cc/MU0PC6, and i will also leave a print screen. So my question is: Is this achievable using AutoLayout and Swift? If it is can you please help me do it? If not, can you please point to a good tutorial that can help me do it using nibs?

Thank you, and sorry for my english and newbie skills.

Here is the screenshot
[image: Scrollview with multiple views]

Comment: Of course its achievable. But have you tried a little bit? If its multiple views inside a scrollview then what's the problem in designing it if you know autolayout. Start implementing, if somewhere you stuck, post here then only we are able to help you.

Comment: I can't see a problem. Is that just implementation issue? Or you facing some errors?

Comment: i tried to make a scrollview and put a view inside it but it throws it in the middle of the screen even if i constrained it to the top. all the constraints are red

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to create complex scrollable layouts with different elements and sections you should use a UICollectionView.

You can read into it here:
[UICollectionView Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/78550/beginning-ios-collection-views-swift-part-1)

All the different parts of the layout would be individual UICollectionviewCells and you can control the size of them through UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout.

You can also build it using just UIScrollView and AutoLayout of course but the UICollectionView approach saves you a lot of headaches and when developing for iOS the UICollectionView is one of the most vital UI components anyway.